# Refund of USA taxes and Passenger Facility Fees due to itinerary change?

Tags: usa, airlines, airports, tickets, us-airways

USA travel. Initial round trip itinerary DTW/DCA/LGA EWR/DTW.

DTW/DCA leg was canceled by the airline and revised at no charge.

Revised itinerary DTW/LGA EWR/DTW

Any ability to get a refund of the below taxes/fees itemized on US Airs website due to the DTW/DCA leg disappearing from the itinerary ? If yes how would I figure out what the actual PFC charge to be refunded should be ?

$3.70 per flight segment, per passenger (U.S. domestic segment tax)

$2.50 per flight segment, per passenger (September 11th security fee)

$3 to $18 per passenger (Local airports assess Passenger Facility Charges --PFCs-- this amount varies by airport)

Answer (score 5):

Depends on the airline rules and the fare you booked. Generally, if the ticket is refundable - everything should be refundable. The government doesn't charge fees and taxes if you didn't travel. The airline - might.

How to figure the exact fees - your travel agent can probably help you with that, they have that break-down. If you booked online - you might not be able to get this information on the confirmation (I remember getting it from some online booking sites, but definitely not the majority of them).

Remember that the change in the price of your ticket doesn't necessarily reflect the change in your itinerary linearly.

Comment: And often, if your change results in a lower cost you don't get a refund, but if it results in a higher cost, you have to pay the extra.

Comment: @KateGregory : DTW/DCA leg was canceled by the airline and revised at no charge. I revised the question to reflect this

Comment: @ChaimGeretz - So what you're saying is that they moved you from a flight DTW-LGA with a connection at DCA to a flight DTW-LGA with no connections. One could argue that not only you're not entitled for a refund, you should be paying more, since direct flights are usually more expensive. But as I said - it depends on your airline really.

Answer (score 4):

It's a little bit of a grey area, but as a rule when your flights change due to circumstances beyond your control (including schedule changes like this, delayed flights, etc) then the price you pay - including fees - doesn't change, regardless of any differences in either the fare or taxes.

In this case the difference in taxes and fees would be around $11 less, but the difference in the fare for the direct flight could be hundreds of dollars extra - so the nett result is that you've probably come out a long way in front due to the change.

In the event that the taxes went up due to the change (eg, if you were traveling via a different airport with a higher PFC) the airline would not charge you any additional to cover it.